# Можно ли случайным образом обратиться к участку памятки указателем с мусором?

Tags: delphi

То есть перед выделением участка памяти указателю присваивается некоторое мусорное значение, может ли оно случайным образом совпасть с уже выделенным участком памяти? Я думаю что да, так как мусорные значение в них хоть и статичны (кстати если кто может поясните пожалуйста мне этот момент) но мусорное значение похоже на значение указателей которые уже указывают на какой-то участок памяти.

Comment: А что значит "мусорные значения статичны"?

Answer (score 4):

Если в вашем указателе случайное значение, то он может указывать совершенно куда угодно. Может быть, на ранее выделенный кусок памяти, может быть, нет.

Представьте себе, что вы стреляете из снайперской винтовки с закрытыми глазами и не целясь. Можете ли вы попасть в цель? Можете, конечно, случайность есть случайность. Можете ли вы промахнуться? Конечно, можете.

Comment: +1, про винтовку чудесное сравнение)

Comment: @DreamChild: спасибо! вот ещё одна [великолепная аналогия](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/276994) (к сожалению, не моя)

Comment: @VladD, отличная ссылка на ответ с +2466!

Comment: @avp: Из них 1 мой.